# Trait bound `chrono::DateTime<Utc>: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` is not satisfied

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I am stuck at this error and not sure how to fix it.

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

Error:

```
 Compiling actix-test v0.1.0 (/Users/b/o/d/Rust/actix-test)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `chrono::DateTime<Utc>: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/app/e/api/products/properties.rs:16:61
     |
16   |     let query_result = web::block(move || properties::table.load::<Property>(&*con).unwrap()).await;
     |                                                             ^^^^ the trait `FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` is not implemented for `chrono::DateTime<Utc>`
     |
     = help: the following implementations were found:
               <chrono::DateTime<Utc> as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, Pg>>
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` for `chrono::DateTime<Utc>`
     = note: 2 redundant requirements hidden
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Bool), Pg>` for `Property`
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<_, Property>` for `schemas::products::properties::table`
note: required by a bound in `load`
    --> /Users/b/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1238:15
     |
1238 |         Self: LoadQuery<Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `load`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

models.rs

```
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use uuid::Uuid;


#[allow(unused)]
#[derive(Queryable, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Property {
    pub prod_prop_uuid: Uuid,
    pub t: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub empl_user_pvt_uuid: Uuid,
    pub deleted: bool,
}
```

/product/properties.rs

```
use crate::app::db::connection::DbPool;
use actix_web::{get, web, HttpResponse, Responder};
use diesel::prelude::*;

#[get("/product/properties")]
pub async fn list(db_pool: web::Data<DbPool>) -> impl Responder {
    use crate::app::db::models::products::Property;
    use crate::app::db::schemas::products::properties;

    let con_result = db_pool.get();
    if let Err(e) = con_result {
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("{:?}", e));
    }

    let con = con_result.unwrap();
    let query_result = web::block(move || properties::table.load::<Property>(&*con).unwrap()).await;
    if let Err(e) = query_result {
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("{:?}", e));
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok().json(query_result.unwrap())
}
```

---

Using `PgTimestamp` from `diesel::pg::data_types::PgTimestamp` doesn't seem to solve the problem.

The data type of `t` is `timestampz`.

---

Tried `diesel::pg::types::sql_types::Timestamptz` and `Nullable`

Getting error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>: Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/app/e/api/products/properties.rs:16:61
     |
16   |     let query_result = web::block(move || properties::table.load::<Property>(&*con).unwrap()).await;
     |                                                             ^^^^ the trait `Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>`
     |
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Bool), Pg>` for `(uuid::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, uuid::Uuid, bool, uuid::Uuid, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<BigDecimal>, BigDecimal, std::option::Option<BigDecimal>, std::option::Option<BigDecimal>, std::option::Option<BigDecimal>, std::option::Option<BigDecimal>, std::option::Option<BigDecimal>, bool)`
     = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Bool, diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>, diesel::sql_types::Bool), Pg>` for `Property`
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<_, Property>` for `schemas::products::properties::table`
note: required by a bound in `load`
    --> /Users/b/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1238:15
     |
1238 |         Self: LoadQuery<Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/app/db/models/products.rs:15:5
     |
15   |     pub t: Nullable<Timestamptz>,
     |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>`
     |
note: required by a bound in `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
    --> /Users/b/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.137/src/ser/mod.rs:1899:12
     |
1899 |         T: Serialize;
     |            ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>: serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src/app/db/models/products.rs:15:5
     |
15   |     pub t: Nullable<Timestamptz>,
     |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>`
     |
note: required by a bound in `next_element`
    --> /Users/b/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.137/src/de/mod.rs:1725:12
     |
1725 |         T: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `next_element`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>: serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src/app/db/models/products.rs:15:5
     |
15   |     pub t: Nullable<Timestamptz>,
     |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>`
     |
note: required by a bound in `next_value`
    --> /Users/b/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.137/src/de/mod.rs:1864:12
     |
1864 |         V: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `next_value`
```

Comment: The error says your database type is `Nullable<Timestampz>` try using an option: `Option<DateTime<Utc>>`

Comment: @kmdreko From diesel::sql_types::Nullable?

Comment: @kmdreko Tried. Getting `16   |     let query_result = web::block(move || properties::table.load::<Property>(&*con).unwrap()).await;
     |                                                             ^^^^ the trait `Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>, Pg>` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz>`

Comment: I said use an option, and even written it out for you: `Option<DateTime<Utc>>`

Comment: Something to know about diesel: there are native types (`i32`, `Option`, `DateTime`), and there are database types (`Integer`, `Nullable`, `Timestampz`). Your code should almost always use native types since the database types are just markers to map native types to the database schema.

Comment: Thanks! The option solved it. And thanks for clarifying regarding the native types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're getting is complaining about the mapping from a database field that is `Nullable<Timestampz>` to a `DateTime<Utc>`. There [already exists a mapping](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html#impl-FromSql%3CTimestamptz%2C%20Pg%3E-for-DateTime%3CUtc%3E) from `Timestampz` to `DateTime<Utc>`, but what would it do if the value is `null`? The best way to handle this in your `Property` struct is to use an `Option` which will be `None` if the database value is `null`:

```
pub struct Property {
    pub prod_prop_uuid: Uuid,
    pub t: Option<DateTime<Utc>>, // <-----
    pub empl_user_pvt_uuid: Uuid,
    pub deleted: bool,
}
```